# AJAX not sending parameters over

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'll get straight to the point.

I have a a list which shows everyone in the db who has confirmed that they'll be attending a match. I want the list to change depending on what group is chosen from a select box.

Here's what I have so far: **html & AJAX**

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <script>
            function showUser(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("attendYes").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else { 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("attendingYes").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","attending.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <form>
            <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
              <option value="">Select a group:</option>
              <option value="CMA">CMA</option>
              <option value="CM1">CM1</option>
              <option value="CP2">CP2</option>
              <option value="CBBC">CBBC</option>
              </select>
            </form>
            <br>
            <div id="attendYes"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

And here is the '**attending.php**' page that the choice is meant to be sent to:

```
            <?php
            $q = intval($_GET['q']);

            $con = mysqli_connect('-----','-----','-----','-----');
            if (!$con) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }

            mysqli_select_db($con,"handsomejack_co_forms");
            $sql="SELECT * FROM stats WHERE activity='".$q."' AND attend='0' ORDER BY username ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

I have changed the sql from ".$q." to a defined choice - like CMA - and it worked, so I know the issue comes from sending q over.

Any ideas as to what could be the problem?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you checked with the debugger what is being passed to the js function.

Comment: `document.getElementById("txtHint")` isn't id is wrong here?

Comment: @Jai my mistake, I had already changed that but for some reason copied the old version! Have edited for future ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are <strike>two</strike> three things i would suggest:

A.)
Change the id of the target div. as you have `attendYes` and you are using `txtHint`.

B.) @ js
You can try sending the query in the `.send()` like below.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","attending.php",true);
xmlhttp.send("q=" + encodeURIComponent(str));
```

C.) and @ php:

You should not use `intval()` although i am not very good at php but as per documentation it is something else. so i suggest you to change this:

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

to this:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

Comment: Thank you Jai, it was the intval() - only meant to be used for integers and I forgot to get rid of it when I changed the select names to words.

Comment: @HandsomeJack You are welcome and glad to be a help.

Comment: Hey, I know this isn't about the above question, but if I wanted to use this for two other options, how should I go about it? i.e. The exampleabove shows a list for those saved as attending, I would want to generate lists for not attending, and unconfirmed. (We can move this to a chat instead?)

Answer (score 1):

There's no element like `document.getElementById("txtHint")`. Update it with correct one:

```
document.getElementById("attendYes").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I copied the wrong edition into the code. I had already changed that, hence why the list populates when i used a defined group instead of trying to use 'q'. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you use Jquerys [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Method instead.
It´s easier to implement and it´s runing in all Major Browsers.