# Printing three different lists depending on select box - via PHP & AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I guess this links back to my [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242973/ajax-not-sending-parameters-over)

I have a select box which prints a list of names out depending on whether they have confirmed they'll be attending an event.

```
<html>
     <head>
            <script>

            $('#users option').click(function() {
               $(this).clone().appendTo("#users2");
            });
            </script>
            <script>
            function showUser(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("attendYes").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else { 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("attendYes").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","attending.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                    }
            }
            </script>

            </head>
            <body>

            <form>
            <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value);">
              <option value="">Select a group:</option>
              <option value="CMA">CMA</option>
              <option value="CM1">CM1</option>
              <option value="CP2">CP2</option>
              <option value="CBBC">CBBC</option>
              </select>
            </form>
            <form>
            <select name="users2" value="">
              <option value="">--</option>
            </select>
            </form>
            <form>
            <select name="users3" value="">
              <option value="">--</option>
            </select>
            </form>
            <br>
            <div id="attendYes"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
            <div id="attendNo"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
            <div id="attendUn"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

The list of players is retrieved via attending.php for now - though I have create notattending.php and unconfirm.php with the relevant SQL changes made in each (I figured it'd be easier?).

```
            <?php
            $q = $_GET['q'];

            $con = mysqli_connect('------','------','------','------');
            if (!$con) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }

            mysqli_select_db($con,"handsomejack_co_forms");
            $sql="SELECT * FROM stats WHERE activity='".$q."' AND attend='1' ORDER BY username ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

What I want to happen is for the group selected in 'users' to be set as the group for 'users2' and 'users3', allowing them to print their own lists in 'attendNo' and 'attendUn'.

As you can see in the first code block, I have attempted to clone the data to no avail and I have no idea what to even attempt next.

Has anyone got any suggestions or something to help point me in the right direction?

**Edit - I now have the list printing to all three areas (Yes, No, Unconfirmed), but it still only prints one sql result. Updated Script and SQL below**

```
                            <script>
            function showUser(str) {
                    if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("attendYes").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else { 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("attendYes").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","attending.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("attendNo").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else { 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("attendNo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","attending.php?w="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("attendUn").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else { 
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("attendUn").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","attending.php?e="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }

            }   

            </script>

            <?php
            $q = $_GET['q'];
            $w = $_GET['w'];
            $e = $_GET['e'];

            $con = mysqli_connect('------','------','------','------');
            if (!$con) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }

            mysqli_select_db($con,"handsomejack_co_forms");
            $sql="SELECT * FROM stats WHERE activity='".$q."' AND attend='1' ORDER BY username ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            $sql="SELECT * FROM stats WHERE activity='".$w."' AND attend='2' ORDER BY username ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            $sql="SELECT * FROM stats WHERE activity='".$e."' AND attend='0' ORDER BY username ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            echo "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

Comment: Using `mysqli_` functions is not enough to prevent SQL injection. You should be using parameterized queries too

Comment: thank you @AlvaroMontoro, will add that in now!

Comment: As for the question, you should have each AJAX call done individually instead of trying to fit all of them into one (right now you will get the same result for the three lists). Also, if you are using jQuery (I don't see it in the code, although the question is tagged with it), it would be simpler to use `$.ajax()`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro when I tried to separate them, only the third one would show..

Comment: How did the code look like?

Comment: I've put it in the place of the old edit @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Try using 3 different variables (e.g. xmlhttp, xmlhttp1 and xmlhttp2). Does it fail then? Also, the PHP code seems to return 3 tables independently of the query